# Using an entire sheet as the VLOOKUP table array

Tags: vba, vlookup

I have a worksheet that is comprised entirely of just data.  The worksheet is declared & set in code and I am keying off the first column in the sheet as well.

I tried it and got an error, but was wondering if this is possible.  Can I set that entire sheet as a range that can be passed into the VLOOOKUP?

.Cells(row, col) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup("key", sheetname, [SomeCol].Column, 0)

Error is 1004: Unable to get the VLOOKUP property of the WorkSheetFunction class.

Comment: Show your code, and provide the exact error.  Is your sheet really completely full?  1M rows x 16k columns of data?  That's a lot.

Comment: What I meant was that I'm only using this sheet to store data to lookup. It is not completely filled up. I'm just wondering if I could get away with not defining a range within the sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is a contiguous table (with no empty rows or columns) then (e.g)

```
Range("A1").CurrentRegion
```

will return the range which contains data.

```
.Cells(row, col) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup("key", _
               Worksheets("sheetName").Range("A1").CurrentRegion, _
               colNum, False)
```

FYI the approach above will cause a run-time error if the vlookup doesn't find a match.  This version avoids that by dropping the `WorksheetFunction`:

```
Dim v

v = Application.VLookup("key", _
               Worksheets("sheetName").Range("A1").CurrentRegion, _
               colNum, False)

.Cells(row, col) = IIf(IsError(v), "Not found", v)
```